# Minecraft 1.7.9 won't launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded the launcher (from www.minecraft.net) after purchasing and registering. I run windows 7 ultimate (YES, i downloaded the windows .exe version). I start the launcher and it works fine. I sign in, works fine. I hit play, and all seems normal, until the Mojang screen pops up. Stays up for maybe 3 or 4 seconds, then it will crash back to the launcher. Does this over and over again. Ive tried re-downloading minecraft, re-installing java, several things. Error log reads as follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x053c3e88, pid=3680, tid=648
#
#  JRE version: Java(tm) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19)  (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
#  Java VM: Java HotSpot(tm) client VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode, sharing windows x86 )
#  Problematic frame:
#  C  [ig4dev32.dll+0x3e88]
#
#  Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not allowed by default on client versions of windows
#
#  If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#    http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#  The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
#  See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: I guess pound keys makes things bold, but there are supposed to be (#) signs in front of everyline, not bolded giant letters. My bad.

Comment: What are the specs for your computer?

Comment: My uneducated guess... Did you specify a unique location or anything when minecraft was initially installed. Seems like a miscommunication between where the program wants to write info. And where it then expects to find the info.